# Issue with passing value to view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

) 
I am trying to order my products by price and I keep getting the same message error : Undefined index: title (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\eshop\resources\views\content\item.blade.php)

From what I understood my "item" wasn't  added correctly to $data but I can't figure it out what is the correct way.

My Route :

```
Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting-{sort?}', 'ShopController@products');
```

My view in content.products:

```
 @if($products)   

   <br><br> 
   <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-asc')}}" style="color:black"> High to low</a> |
  <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-desc')}}" style="color:black">Low to high</a>
```

My item.blade.php:

```
@extends ('master') 

@section('content') 
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"> 
    @if('item') 
    <h1>{{ $item['title']}}</h1>  
    <p><img width="500" src="{{ asset ('images/' . $item['image'])}}" </p>  
    <p>{!! $item['article'] !!}</p>
    <p><b>Price on site:</b>{{ $item['price']}}$</p> 
    <p>  
        @if(Cart::get($item['id']))  
        <input disabled="disabled" type="button" value="In Cart!" class="btn btn-success">
        @else 
        <input data-id="{{ $item['id']}}" type="button" value="+ Add to cart" class="btn btn-success add-to-cart"> 
        @endif

        <a href="{{ url('shop/checkout') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</a> 
    </p>
        @else 
        <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 18px">No product details ...</p>  
    @endif 
    </p>
@endsection
```

My Controller:

```
public function products(Request $request, $category_url, $sort= 'ASC'){
   Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);
    $catsort = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first();
    $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $catsort->id)->orderBy('price', $sort)->get(); 
    return view('content.products', self::$data ,['products' => $products, 'sort' => $sort]); 
}  
public function item($category_url, $product_url){ 

       Product::getItem($product_url, self::$data);  
       return view('content.item', self::$data);
   }
```

My Model:

```
static public function getProducts($category_url, &$data){

$data['products']=$data['category']=[];


if ($category=Categorie::where('url','=', $category_url)->first()){

    $category= $category->toArray();
    $data['category']=$category;
    $data['title']=$data['title']. ' | ' . $category['title'];


    if ($products=Categorie::find( $category['id'])->products){

        $data['products']= $products->toArray();
    }
}
} 

static public function getItem($product_url, &$data) {

        $data['item'] = [];

        if ($product = Product::where('url', '=', $product_url)->first()) {

            $product = $product->toArray();
            $data['item'] = $product;
            $data['title'] .= '|' . $product['title'];  

        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't repost questions; if you have additional insights *edit your question* rather than post another one.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `$data` from the controller to the view with `view('content.products', self::$data, ...)`.

In your model, you add the product data to `$data['item']` which will be accessible in the view template through the variable `$item`, and then you add the product title to `$data['title']`, which then will be accessible in the view template through the variable `$title`.

This should be working, as long as your product data is being loaded correctly, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Try to replace in the view template `{{ $item['title']}}` with `{{ $title }}`. If this result in an empty title, then it means that the product data is not being loaded correctly. To make sure you can try to dump the data in the view with `{{ dd($item) }}`.

**EDIT**

There is a problem with your `routes.php` and the route you posted here doesn't seem to be the problem, but the other one probably is.

If you defined it as `Route::get('shop/{category_url}/{product_url}', ...)`, both routes will match the URL `/category/sorting-asc`.

You could add something to the URL to say it is a product URL

```
Route::get('shop/{category_url}/product/{product_url}', ...);
```

Comment: I did as you said but know it shows me the next $item [ ] and now the message error  is Undefined index: image (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myhero\resources\views\content\item.blade.php) . Here is my view :https://pastebin.com/mmRfkm9F

Comment: {{ dd($item) }} return empty array [ ]

Comment: check if `$product_url` is being passed correctly to the controller

Comment: Not sure where exactly I should check this

Comment: you can add `dd($product_url)` in the controller `item` method, and maybe also check the product data there

Comment: its echo "sorting-desc" and "sorting-asc"  in accordance of the link I click

Comment: can you please check my product.blade.php https://pastebin.com/zZGUEXNS I feel like maybe there is also an issue

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it

Comment: I fixed my route to Route::get('shop/{category_url}/product/{product_url}','ShopController@products'); as you sugested ...but I don't  understand  what you meant by saying add something to the URL to say it is a product URL , the one in products.blade.php ?